# How to detect if an attribute contains a certain value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have elements with various values for an attribute (ids="32, 56, 21"). How can I get the elements that contain 21?

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the name of the attribute you're selecting? A HTML snippet would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this:

```
$("[ids~=21]")
```

there must be a space between the attribute values.

You may have to use:

```
 $("[ids~=21],[ids~=21,]")
```

see this link: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/